# PHP strict compare two objects is false

Tags: php, arrays, object, comparison

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->first = 'James';
$a->last = 'Doe';

$b = (object) [
    'first' => 'James',
    'last' => 'Doe',
];

echo 'Loose compare: ' . ($a == $b ? 'equal' : 'different') . PHP_EOL; // equal
echo 'Type compare: ' . (gettype($a) == gettype($b) ? 'equal' : 'different') . PHP_EOL; // equal
echo 'Strict compare: ' . ($a === $b ? 'equal' : 'different') . PHP_EOL; // different
```

How come strict compare is no good? And more importantly can they be made strictly the same?

Comment: `$b = $a; echo ($a === $b ? 'equal' : 'different') . PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strict compare checks if `$a` and `$b` are the **exact same** object (same memory location). The only way to make them the same (strictly) would be  `$a = $b;`

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php for reference

Comment: so.. the offic manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php says
"$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type."
should it then also mention "and occupy the same memory location"? or rather particularly to this case "and if they are objects then they are the same instance"

Comment: From the doc page you link it would really seem that `$a === $b` should be true for two instances of the same class with equal attribute values. The "object comparison" page is more precise. Maybe you should report this as a bug (there is a link in the documentation).